# wordpress - adding custom post data from frontend + recaptcha

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, recaptcha

I've got my own piece of code which is responsible for adding data into specific custom post type. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "opinie-klientow") {
    //store our post vars into variables for later use
    //now would be a good time to run some basic error checking/validation
    //to ensure that data for these values have been set
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $post_type = 'opinie-klientow';
    $custom_field_1 = $_POST['testimonials-author'];
    $current_date = date("m-d-y");
    $before_date = "Opinia" . " ";

    //the array of arguements to be inserted with wp_insert_post
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $before_date . " " . $current_date . " " . $custom_field_1,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => $post_type
    );

    //insert the the post into database by passing $new_post to wp_insert_post
    //store our post ID in a variable $pid
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //we now use $pid (post id) to help add out post meta data
    if (!add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-testimonials-author', $custom_field_1, true)) {
        update_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-testimonials-author', $custom_field_1);
    }
}

?>
<form method="post" name="front_end" id="testimonialsform" action="">
    <input type="text" name="testimonials-author" class="form-control" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko"/>
    <textarea rows="4" name="content" class="form-control content" placeholder="Treść opinii"/></textarea>
    <input class="antyspam" type="hidden" name="email" tabindex="-1"/>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY-XXXX" data-theme="light" data-type="audio"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-violet submit" value="Dodaj opinię"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="opinie-klientow"/>
</form>
```

What if I would like to combine that with the following piece of code (responsible for recaptcha:

```
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
} else {
    $validated = false;
    $errors['recaptcha'] = __("Kod reCAPTCHA nie został wprowadzony poprawnie. Spróbuj ponownie.", 'domain.com');
}
```

I've tried adding it at the begining of my code but it just not working..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [WP Recaptcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha/) .? if not install it, and update your re-captcha `site_key` on their config screen.

and then update your template like this ( especially the recaptcha section )

```
<?php $reOptions = WPPlugin::retrieve_options("recaptcha_options"); ?>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $reOptions['site_key']; ?>" data-theme="light" data-type="audio"></div>
```

and on your php part ( the code responsible to insert custom post )

```
if( isset( $_POST['response_field'] ) && !empty( $_POST['response_field'] ) ) {

    $reOptions = WPPlugin::retrieve_options("recaptcha_options");   
    $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha( $reOptions['secret'] );

    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse (
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        $_POST['response_field']
    );

    if ( !$response->success ) {
        // re Captcha validation failed
    } else {
        // re Captcha success, do your stuff here   
        // In your case put your post insertion code here
    }

} else {
    // re Captcha field itself missing
}
```

Comment: i use recaptcha via contact form 7 Integration. I would like to avoid installing another recaptcha plugin. If I already have such solution should I use your PHP?